# Request HTTP ionic 2 GET

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular

Boa tarde pessoal, uso ionic 2 e como posso fazer um request get (sem provider nd só na classe ts)? preciso só que pegue o que esta escrito na página e exiba em um alert. Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples, injete o Http do angular e depois faça a requisição.
Depois disso, basta fazer um alert usando algum component do ionic.

Dependendo do site que você for fazer a requisição, pode acontecer de ter problema com CORS ([tópico relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166491/ionic-2-erro-http-request/180408)).

Exemplo:

```
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(
        private http: Http, 
        private alertCtrl: AlertController) { }

requisicao() {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams;
        params.set('parametro1', 'bla');
        params.set('parametro2', 'bla2');

    this.http.get('http://..., {
        search: params
    }).toPromise().then(response => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Good Lock!',
            subTitle: response,
            buttons: ['OK']
        });

        alert.present();
    });
}
```

Obs: Lembrando que fazer tudo junto (na mesma classe) pode deixar seu código mais acoplado e menos coeso. Tente separar adequadamente as responsabilidades das classes.