# IOnic 2 erro http request

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic2, angular

Estou precisando fazer um request a um webserver no ionic 2 e estou com o seguinte codigo :

```html
constructor(private navController: NavController, public http: Http) {
      var url = 'http://localhost/APIPortManager/teste.php';
      var response = this.http.get(url)
      response.toPromise().then(response => {
         
          let dados = response.json()
          alert (dados)
      }).catch(err => {
      //let erro = err.json();
          alert ("erro")
      });
        //return response;
      //alert(response.toPromise()); // return object object
  }
```

Porem só me retorna o erro, como faço para exibir o texto ?
Obrigado
Ps: eu sei que o correto não é no controller, só preciso exibir o código que a pg tem, não preciso nem do json se a pg exibir oi quero dar alert em oi só isso.
Atualização, erro no console :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No teste.php, você precisa adicionar alguns HEADERS na resposta (também conhecido como CORS).

Tem um exemplo aqui: [ionic2 - upload de foto via servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176788/ionic2-upload-de-foto-via-servidor/180406)

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```